# Would you recommend graston technique for achilles tendonosis?

Tags: injury, tendons

I like to play basketball and when I do I usually play for 2-3 hours. Sometimes non-stop sometimes with breaks. Depends on how much I win, as in basketball its about king of the court. One days where I play a lot, my achilles tendon gets sore. I've noticed massaging the tendon helps, but sometimes in the morning I feel the stiffness even though I am only 20 years old. I have seen youtube videos on how garrison technique works but many studies show that it is not that beneficial. One study concluded that it takes the worse of the pain off and one done with mice concluded that it might help humans but much more testing is needed. One study even noted that it's benefit was unnoticeable and any benefit should be from a placebo effect. Are there any other things one would recommend for achilles tendonitis or rather I believe it is achilles tendonosis as my achilles tendon does not swell?

Link about studies:https://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/the-graston-technique-inducing-microtrauma-with-instruments/

Comment: How long have you been playing for (months/years)? How many times a week do you play?

Comment: Since my freshman year of high school so six years. It started in 11th grade when I noticed pains in my achilles tendon. And the amount varied though high school it was once to twice a week. Except for summer which is was more like 5 days a week in HS. In college I play usually 3/4 days a week.